# partman configuration in preseed.cfg to ignore multiple drive warning

Tags: debian-installer, preseed

I can't find the parameter that could ignore the "multiple disks found" warning. This is what my partman part looks like:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sdb
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```

The goal is to create the LVM partitions on /dev/sdb whithout raising any warnings. Do I have an order problem or something?

Answer (score 1):

To answer to myself,

I've looked through the */var/og/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat* file after a handmade install
It's a pretty useful file and all the question you ever asked is inside this file.
I Just had to had the question that was bothering me (a note type) and that was good to go

Answer (score 1):

Seems that, at least in Jessie, the path of this file changed to `/var/lib/cdebconf/questions.dat`